# Using ammonite repl for Scala scripting

Tags: scala, ammonite

when having a script file (file.sc) with the following content:

```
import ammonite._, Resolvers._

val mock_client_repo = Resolver.Http("Unisay at bintray","http://dl.bintray.com/unisay/maven",MavenPattern,true)

interp.resolvers() = interp.resolvers() :+ mock_client_repo

import $ivy.`com.github.unisay::mockserver-client-scala:0.2.0`

import org.mockserver.client.server.MockServerClient
import com.github.unisay.mockserver.scala.DSL.Statuses._
import com.github.unisay.mockserver.scala.DSL._

val port = 3000
val host = "127.0.0.1"
implicit val server = new MockServerClient(host,port)

forAnyRequest respond Ok
```

which I'm trying to execute as follows: *amm files.sc*
I get the following error:

> Compiling file.sc :: loading settings :: url =
>   jar:file:/usr/local/bin/amm!/org/apache/ivy/core/settings/ivysettings.xml
>   :: resolving dependencies ::
>   com.github.unisay#mockserver-client-scala_2.11-caller;working     confs:
>   [default]
>
> :: problems summary :: :::: WARNINGS      module not found:
>   com.github.unisay#mockserver-client-scala_2.11;0.2.0
>
> ==== local: tried
>
> /home/eli/.ivy2/local/com.github.unisay/mockserver-client-scala_2.11/0.2.0/ivys/ivy.xml
>
> ```
> -- artifact
> ```
>
> com.github.unisay#mockserver-client-scala_2.11;0.2.0!mockserver-client-scala_2.11.jar:
>
> /home/eli/.ivy2/local/com.github.unisay/mockserver-client-scala_2.11/0.2.0/jars/mockserver-client-scala_2.11.jar
>
> ==== m2: tried
>
> /home/eli/.m2/repository/com/github/unisay/mockserver-client-scala_2.11/0.2.0/ivy-0.2.0.xml
>
> ```
> -- artifact
> ```
>
> com.github.unisay#mockserver-client-scala_2.11;0.2.0!mockserver-client-scala_2.11.jar:
>
> /home/eli/.m2/repository/com/github/unisay/mockserver-client-scala_2.11/0.2.0/mockserver-client-scala_2.11-0.2.0.jar
>
> ==== central: tried
>
> http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/unisay/mockserver-client-scala_2.11/0.2.0/mockserver-client-scala_2.11-0.2.0.pom
>
> ```
> -- artifact
> ```
>
> com.github.unisay#mockserver-client-scala_2.11;0.2.0!mockserver-client-scala_2.11.jar:
>
> http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/unisay/mockserver-client-scala_2.11/0.2.0/mockserver-client-scala_2.11-0.2.0.jar
>
> :: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS Exception in
>   thread "main" ammonite.runtime.tools.IvyThing$IvyResolutionException:
>   failed to resolve ivy dependencies unresolved dependency:
>   com.github.unisay#mockserver-client-scala_2.11;0.2.0: not found

But if running the same code copy pasted from within the repl, everything works fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You could try to place the import at the beginning of the file.  I do so and it works.

Comment: @david.perez I guess you meant the `import $ivy` part ?!   
But I can not place it before I've updated my resolvers, it wouldn't make any   
scene.

Comment: That's true.  It must be a bug in Ammonite.  Ammonite is updated very frequently, maby upgrading it, solves the problem.  Otherwise I would open a bug in the github repo.

Comment: @david.perez Someone else did it more than two weeks ago(#491), but no comment from the maintainers.

Comment: Yeah issue #491 is still open. I haven't had time to investigate and properly fix it. Hopefully someone can step up to the plate and help out

Comment: Seeing that #491 is closed I tried this in 0.9.1 but it chokes on the first `import`.  Is this code obsolete or is it my environment?  I don't really understand everything that is happening here, like where `Resolvers` comes from.  Is it `ammonite.Resolvers`?

Answer (score 0):

http://ammonite.io/#Multi-stageScripts

> By default, everything in a script is compiled and executed as a
>   single block. While you can use Magic Imports to load other scripts or
>   Ivy artifacts before your script runs, those can only load "hardcoded"
>   scripts or artifacts, and cannot e.g. load different scripts depending
>   on some runtime variables.
>
> If you want to load different scripts or ivy artifacts depending on
>   runtime values, you can use the runtime-equivalent of magic imports:

- `import $cp` becomes `interp.load.cp`
- `import $file` becomes `interp.load.module`
- `import $ivy` becomes `interp.load.ivy`

in your case, 
change

```
import $ivy.`com.github.unisay::mockserver-client-scala:0.2.0`
```

to

```
interp.load.ivy("com.github.unisay" %% "mockserver-client-scala" % "0.2.0")
```